# Using Fancybox with Image map

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, lightbox

I wonder if there is a way to use the fancybox with Image maps?

```
    <img src="\path\" usemap="#Map">
    <map name="Map" id="Map" >
      <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,0,328,145,328" href="#" />
      <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,180,0,328,328,142,328" href="#" />        
      <area shape="poly" coords="328,328,328,0,180,0" href="#" />    
    </map>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So you want to show a single image in a fancybox with an image map?

It is possible to add the map to the image of fancybox in a couple of ways,

For example, you could add it to an image once its loaded, the image will load with the id `fancybox-img`, so using the [`oncomplete()`](http://fancybox.net/api) callback we can have access to add the map to the image:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="/path/to/large/image" class="fancybox" title="Single image with a map">
    <img src="/path/to/small/image"/>
</a>
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,0,328,145,328" href="#" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,180,0,328,328,142,328" href="#" />        
    <area shape="poly" coords="328,328,328,0,180,0" href="#" />    
</map>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'titleShow': true,
    'titlePosition': 'inside',
    onComplete: function() {
        $('#fancybox-img').attr('usemap', '#Map');
    }
});
```

[**See it working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ffZ7B/)

---

The other way is to pass content to the fancybox:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="/path/to/small/image" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
   <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,0,328,145,328" href="#" />
   <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,180,0,328,328,142,328" href="#" />        
   <area shape="poly" coords="328,328,328,0,180,0" href="#" />    
</map>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("img").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    var content = '<img src="'+url+'" usemap="#Map" />';
    $.fancybox({
        'title'   : 'Single image with a map',
        'titlePosition': 'inside',
        'content' : content
    });
});
```

[**See it working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ffZ7B/1/)

---

The above could be improved to support multiple images and maps by doing something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="/path/to/small/image" rel="#Map" title="Single image with a map 1" class="fancybox" />
<br />
<img src="/path/to/second/small/image" rel="#Map"  title="Single image with a map 2" class="fancybox" />
<br />
<img src="/path/to/non/fancybox/image" />
<br/>
Try clicking image to enlarge....
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,0,328,145,328" href="#" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,180,0,328,328,142,328" href="#" />        
    <area shape="poly" coords="328,328,328,0,180,0" href="#" />    
</map>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("img.fancybox").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    var map = $(this).attr('rel');
    var title = $(this).attr('title'); 
    var content = '<img src="' + url + '" usemap="'+ map + '" />';
    $.fancybox({
        'title': title,
        'titlePosition': 'inside',
        'content': content
    });
});
```

[**See it working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ffZ7B/2/)

***NOTE:** I have added a couple of options to the fancybox, like the title just to show how you can add the options. I also caught the click on the map so it didn't open the url and alerts just to show you the map is working.*

---

***Update as per the comments:***

Ahh, I misunderstood. In that case, it is quite simple to use a fancybox when a user clicks on a map item. The simplest, is to use the jQuery selector `$('map > area')` to catch any click on an area of a map. However, if you didn't want ALL area's to open in a fancybox, it might be better to add to your selector, for example give each area that you want to open a fancybox a class, then use the selector `$('map > area.fancybox')`:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="/path/to/image" usemap="#Map" />
<br />
Try clicking image map.....
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,0,328,145,328" href="http://www.google.com" class="fancybox" title="Google" rel="iframe" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="0,0,180,0,328,328,142,328" href="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5177/5574889454_b0a8c7845b.jpg" class="fancybox" title="EBR 1190 Typhon hits the track" rel="image" />        
    <area shape="poly" coords="328,328,328,0,180,0" href="http://www.ask.com" />
</map>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('map > area.fancybox').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var type = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.fancybox({
        'title': title,
        'titlePosition': 'inside',
        'href' : url,
        'type' : type
    });
});
```

[**See the example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ffZ7B/4/)

- So in the example above, we use the jQuery `.click()` to catch any clicks on a map area with the class fancybox *(you will notice the www.ask.com example will open in the window, the other two open in a fancybox)*.
- We use the `.preventDefault()` method to stop the browser following the link like it normally would.
- Next get the url of the area clicked on.
- Then get the title of the area clicked on *(not really needed, but just added to try and help show how you can get data)*
- Next I set the type using the `rel` attribute, this allows you to set what you want the fancybox to do.
- Now simply open the fancybox with the details.

So in this example:

Area 1 will open a fancybox which is an iframe containing a page.

Area 2 will open a fancybox with an image in it.

Area 3 will just load the website in the link as normal not using fancybox.

Comment: thanks for your response but I think you missed my point. My Question is that I want to make mapping for image (define areas in the image) when clicking on any area it opens fancybox or lightbox. did you got me?

Comment: @Mohamed Amgad I did indeed misunderstand your question. I have added to the answer, its another example, allowing you to use fancybox from an image map - I've included a couple of examples how you can use this. I hope this helps!

Comment: It looks like the latest fancybox handle for the loaded image is $('.fancybox-image').