# My FancyBox won't run...using a single image with image maps

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm trying to use FancyBox on an image, divided into 4 image maps. I found this post: [Using Fancybox with Image map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530871/using-fancybox-with-image-map), and duplicated the resources used and js, but mine doesn't seem to want to run...? Please help!

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.acquafibrausa.com/images/caps_top.png" usemap="#Map">
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
       <area shape="rect" coords="43,91,177,141" href="http://www.acquafibrausa.com/images/nutrition_lime.png"
class="fancybox" alt="Click to view Lime nutrition facts" rel="image" />
       <area shape="rect" coords="264,92,399,142" href="http://www.acquafibrausa.com/images/nutrition_orange.png"
class="fancybox" alt="Click to view Orange nutrition facts" rel="image"
/>
       <area shape="rect" coords="488,92,622,143" href="http://www.acquafibrausa.com/images/nutrition_strawberry.png"
class="fancybox" alt="Click to view Strawberry nutrition facts" rel="image"
/>
       <area shape="rect" coords="711,90,846,142" href="http://www.acquafibrausa.com/images/nutrition_peach.png"
class="fancybox" alt="Click to view Peach nutrition facts" rel="image"
/>
    </map>
```

JQUERY/head content:

```
<link href="main_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('map > area.fancybox').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   var title = $(this).attr('title');
   var type = $(this).attr('rel');
   $.fancybox({
      'title': title,
      'titlePosition': 'inside',
      'href' : url,
      'type' : type
   });
});
</script>
```

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/amandabeau/FvG8p/)

There there's an above example on jsfiddle.

Comment: In the browser console, does it sends you an error or warning?

Comment: nope, the images just open in a new page. The map just behaves like normal, as if I wasn't trying to run FancyBox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open fancybox using map link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412483/how-to-open-fancybox-using-map-link)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included jQuery. To do it in your Fiddle, look at your at the [right side of the page](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-aM3i7CypSVNXNtN3BCMURqeTg/edit). To do it on your real page look [here](http://jquery.com/download/), the most simple way is *Using jQuery with a CDN*.

It appears only to work with jQuery 1.8.3 and below (I tried the default versions available in jsFiddle).

And you haven't closed your image tag.

Comment: The image is from a fiddle from the post you referred to.

Comment: Thanks!I've included 1.8.3 in the jsFiddle example as well as the real page. It works in jsFiddle now, but still doesn't want to run on my page...?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by I "haven't closed my image tag"? All my tags look complete to me, what am i missing?

Comment: You seem to have jQuery version 1.4.3. But the main error appears to be that it fails to load the fancybox js-file. If you open the page in Google Chrome and open the inspector (ctrl+shift+i WIN or cmd+alt+i MAC) and go to the Consol tab and reload the page. I get the following error: 
 `GET` [file location] `404 (Not Found) `. Have you uploaded the script file to your server?
And the img tag should be `<img src="images/caps_top.png" usemap="map"** /**>`

Comment: Ignore the *-symbols, I tried to make the slash bold.
`<img src="images/caps_top.png" usemap="map" />`

Comment: I noticed that you fixed the fancybox-link and that it still doesn't work. I also saw that you've included jQuery twice, once from your server, and once from Google's. Try removing one, and placing the second above the line where you load the fancybox-script. I'd also try a newer version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to open fancybox **FROM** an image map (also answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418310/1055987), then you just need to bind the `area` tag to fancybox, either doing :

```
$("#Map area").fancybox();
```

... if the `area` tag has not any class, or :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

... assuming that the `area` tag has `class="fancybox"`.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AA6mN/)** ....

Regarding your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amandabeau/FvG8p/) you were linking to jQuery using this link : http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.4/jquery.min.js but that returns a 404 error. Actually it seems like a v1.3.4 of jQuery never existed ;) ... you can check http://code.jquery.com/ for previous versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the script won't load when using the full URL path (i.e. starting with `http://`)

Try loading the image using a relative path: `href="images/image.jpg"`